# Joomla 2.5 404 Error When Submitting PHP Form inside an Article

Tags: php, module, joomla2.5, article

I made my own module to submit a php form's data into the database. I have the module inside of an article now.

When I submit the form, it goes to a 404 error page even though I have another template page for a successful submission.

I have tried using action = post.php as well as the exact URL but it fails.

Does anyone know what I am going wrong?

Here is the URL: http://aubrey-joomla-test.freeiz.com/index.php/new-user-registration-form

Here is my file name for the default template: default_tmpl.php

Here is my tmpl code:

```
<div>
    <form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php'); ?>" method="post" id="myform" class="cols"  >

        <input type="hidden" name="form_send" value="send" />

        <h2>New User Registration Form</h2>
                <table>
                <label>Are you employed?</label>
                <tr>
                    <td><label><input type="radio" name="option" value="1" required="required">Yes</label></td>
                    <td><label><input type="radio" name="option" value="0" required="required">No</label></td>
                </tr>
                <label>If not, please proceed to the next section.</label>
                </table>

          <fieldset name="salary">

            <h4>Income From Employment</h4>             
                <table> <tr><label>Pay cycle:</label>
                    <td><label><input type="radio" name="option1" value="1" required="required">Monthly</label></td>
                    <td><label><input type="radio" name="option1" value="2" required="required">Biweekly</label></td>
                </tr> </table>
            <p><label>Please enter your typical pay: <input type="text" name="amountpay" required="required" pattern="\d+(\.\d{2})?"/> </label></p>
            <p><label>Please select your next pay day: <input type="date" name="paydate"  required="required" /> </label></p>

          </fieldset>

          <fieldset name="fixeditems">
            <h4>Fixed Items</h4>
                <table> <label>Payment cycle:</label> <tr>
                <td><label><input type="radio" name="option2" value="1" required="required">Monthly</label></td>
                <td><label><input type="radio" name="option2" value="2" required="required">Biweekly</label></td>
                <tr>
                </table>

                <table> <label>Is this a form of:</label> <tr>
                    <td><label><input type="radio" name="option3" value="2" required="required">Income</label></td>
                    <td><label><input type="radio" name="option3" value="1" required="required">Expense</label></td>
                <tr>
                </table>        

            <p><label>Please enter the typical amount: <input type="text" name="amount" required="required" pattern ="\d+(\.\d{2})?" /> </label></p>
            <p><label>Please select the next due date: <input type="date"  name="amountdate" required="required" /> </label></p>
          </fieldset>

          <hr>

          <div class="clear"></div>

          <button type="submit" name="send" value="Send">Submit form</button>
          <button type="reset">Reset</button>



</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no code to handle a form submission. You need to add in a hidden field that would trigger additional code that handles the form submission instead of displaying the form. You need something like this in your module -

```
if $_POST["form_submit_trigger"] :

PUT SOME CODE HERE TO HANDLE YOUR SUBMITTED DATA

else

PUT THE CODE TO DISPLAY YOUR FORM HERE
```

form_submit_trigger should be a hidden field in your form that is generated and hashed each time the form is diaplyed. This way you can confirm that the form was actually generated and submitted on your site.